# Deciling by sum of values in R

Tags: r, quantile

I am trying to find a function to decile sum of data in R. While there are quantile functions already built in, these functions divide data in a way that each bucket will have equal number of values, whereas I am looking for output with equal sum of values.

Example - Lets say I have sales made by 100 sales reps. Rep_1 made a sale of 1, rep_2 made a sale of 2 and so on.

```
Rep_ID Sales
Rep1     1
Rep2     2
Rep3     3
....
```

If I decile data by "quantile" function, each bucket will have 10 sales reps in it, whereas I want each bucket to represent 10% of sales. So decile 10 will have top 5 reps as they made a sale of ~500 out of total sale of 5050 made by entire team. Next bucket will have 6 reps, and similarly subsequent buckets will have more number of reps but the sum of each bucket will add to 10% of total sales.

I know the code is simple, but I was just wondering if there is a more flexible and robust built in function for it?

```html
df = as.data.frame(list(paste0("rep", 100:1), 100:1), col.names = c("Rep_ID", "Sales"))

df$decile = ceiling((1 - (cumsum(df$Sales)/sum(df$Sales)))*10)
print(df[1:10,])
```

Comment: You could use `df$decile = as.numeric(cut(cumsum(df$Sales), breaks=10))` - not convinced it's simpler & not sure it gets much simpler than that

Comment: Thanks! I agree.